# How do I access Nancy's CurrentUser property from within a Razor view?

Tags: razor, nancy

I am trying to access the `CurrentUser` property of the `NancyContext`. How do I do this from within the html of a Razor view?

I would be grateful for a code snippet if possible.

Thanks

**Edit**

I now extend `Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.HtmlHelpers` to give me cross-view data with syntactic sugar that keeps the view code terse and readable.

Here are a few examples:

```
public static bool IsRegistered<T>(this HtmlHelpers<T> html)
{
    var user = GetUser(html);
    return user != null && user.IsRegistered;
}

public static bool IsAuthenticated<T>(this HtmlHelpers<T> html)
{
    return GetUser(html) != null;
}

public static User GetUser<T>(this HtmlHelpers<T> html)
{
    return (User)html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser;
}
```

And some razor code from a view. Here I am deciding to include the html for a Sign In popup (Foundation Reveal) only if the user is not currently authenticated - makes sense.

```
@if (!Html.IsAuthenticated())
{
    Html.Partial("Reveals/SignInReveal");
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't put it on the model?

Comment: Yes. The CurrentUser info is used across many views, but not all. So it is easier to centralize this in a single re-usable place rather than having to remember to set up the model for each each view. I find it far more convenient to provide cross-view data via Razor.HtmlHelpers extension methods

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the `NancyContext` through the `Html` property's `RenderContext` property.

A sample usage:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>

<p>Current User: @Html.RenderContext.Context.CurrentUser </p>
```

However if your are using the SuperSimpleViewEngine (thanks the comment to [@Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350933/sean)) then you can do similar using the

```
@Context.CurrentUser.UserName
```

Comment: I know this about Context within a Razor view engine. But if anyone, like myself, stumbled upon this post whilst looking for answers on how to do this within the default SuperSimpleViewEngine, you can do similar using the `@Context` token.  e.g. `@Context.CurrentUser.UserName`